# How to correctly type the configuration Object?

Tags: typescript, highcharts

I have a working graph (i.e. It shows what it is supposed to show and behaves as expected on interactions).

Since I work in TypeScript, I get TS errors on callbacks in the definition of the configuration object, for instance:

```
(...)
point: {
  events: {
    click: function () {
      console.log(this)
      emit('result', phishingMap.value[this.category]) // the error is here
    }
  }
}
(...)
```

This piece of code yields the error

```
Property 'category' does not exist on type '{ click: () => void; }'. TS(2339)
```

How can I fix that by hinting about the content of `this`? The [Highcharts documentation for TS](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/highcharts-typescript-declarations) does not mention any special steps to get the types declarations in.

EDIT: I know about traditional function and fat arrows (and the behaviour of `this`) but the problem is not in how to access the data, but about the data typing.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the TypeScript error and provide type information for the this context inside the callback function, you can use an arrow function instead of a regular function.

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: () => {
      console.log(this);
      emit('result', phishingMap.value[this.category]);
    }
  }
}
```

If you're still encountering issues with type inference, you can explicitly annotate the type of this to provide TypeScript with additional information. For example:

```
point: {
  events: {
    click: function(this: Highcharts.Chart, event: Highcharts.ChartClickEvent) {
      console.log(this);
      emit('result', phishingMap.value[this.category]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is the classic this problem in javascript callbacks. Arrow function are perfect for that indeed.

Comment: (please have a look at my edit) just using a fat arrow does not solve the problem of types in TS - the variable is still not hinted. In other words, `category` is still `any` (as well as everything upstream the chain). Moreover, you can't redefine `this` as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `this` refer to the object you are writting. It has nothing to do with Highcharts but with how JS works while writting a function inside an object.

To keep the reference, you should use an arrow function

```
(...)
point: {
  events: {
    click: () => {
      console.log(this)
      emit('result', phishingMap.value[this.category]) // the error is here
    }
  }
}
(...)
```

Here is the big difference between a classic function and an arrow function :

The first one use the ref of the first parent

The second one use the ref of the class

Comment: (please have a look at my edit) just using a fat arrow does not solve the problem of types in TS - the variable is still not hinted. In other words, category is still any (as well as everything upstream the chain).